# Sequelize belongsToMany get source model by querying on target model

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two models *Brand* and *Campaign*.

A *Brand* can have many *Campaigns*

```
export default(sequelize, DataTypes)=> {
  const Brand = sequelize.define('Brand', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
 })

 Brand.associate = models=> {
    Brand.belongsToMany(models.Campaign, {
        through: models.CampaignBrand,
        foreignKey: 'brand',
    })
 }

 return Brand
}
```

A *Campaign* can also have many *Brand*

```
export default(sequelize, DataTypes)=> {
  const Campaign = sequelize.define('Campaign', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
 })

 Campaign.associate = models=> {
    Campaign.belongsToMany(models.Brand, {
        through: models.CampaignBrand,
        foreignKey: 'campaign',
    })
 }

 return Campaign
}
```

And here is *through* model:

```
export default(sequelize, DataTypes)=> {
  const CampaignBrand = sequelize.define('CampaignBrand', {
    // see enums
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    roleText: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  })

  CampaignBrand.associate = models=> {
    CampaignBrand.belongsTo(models.Campaign, {
        foreignKey: 'campaign',
        targetKey: 'id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
  }

  return CampaignBrand
}
```

In case I want to **get Campaigns** by **brand**. What should I do?
I have tried query likes document mentioned but it does not work for me

> With Belongs-To-Many you can query based on through relation and select specific attributes. For example using findAll with through
>
> User.findAll({
>     include: [{
>       model: Project,
>       through: {
>         attributes: ['createdAt', 'startedAt', 'finishedAt'],
>         where: {completed: true}
>       }
>     }]
>   });

I have found some ways to work around, but it is not what I am looking for:

**SOLUTION 1:**

Update **belongsToMany** *Brand* to **hasMany** *CampaignBrand* and the query by *CampaignBrand.brand*

**SOLUTION 2:**

Get *Campaign* by querying *Brand*

Any other advices?

**Dialect:** postgres

**Database version:** 9.4

**Sequelize version:** 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need this association in the the through model:

`CampaignBrand.associate = models=> {
    CampaignBrand.belongsTo(models.Campaign, {
        foreignKey: 'campaign',
        targetKey: 'id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
  }`

You already have the belongsToMany association in the definitions of Brand and Campaign, so I think you just need to create the CampaignBrand model with your status and roleText attributes.

As I understand it, then you can query brands through campaigns and it should return each brand element and its associated campaigns,

`Brand.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Campaign
  }]
});`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is kinda old, but with belongstomany associations, you can use mixins.

[https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/associations/belongs-to-many.js~belongstomany](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7Ebelongstomany)

```
const campaigns = await CampaignModel.findAll();
const campaignsBrandsModels = await campaigns.getBrandsModels({
        limit:1, 
        through: {where:{pivot_field:'pivot_value'} } // << You want this, i think!
      });
```

Now, remember that, the mixins (get, set, count...) set their name with inflection library, so, a way to set the names without error (or without spending a lot of time searching the name in in the console) is setting an 'as' alias in the Association

```
CampaignBrand.belongsToMany(models.Campaign, {
    through: models.CampaignBrand,
    foreignKey: 'brand',
    as: 'BrandsModels' //<<<< This is Super important! at least for easy usage
})
```

You can achieve this with an include in the findAll method too, BUT!

the 'limit: #' part will not work! (Will give you the error of "This only works with hasMany because separate: true")

I really hope this can help anyone, seya!